# My flutter IOS application working fine in a debug build but not in release mode

Tags: ios, flutter

I am trying to develop a flutter IOS application. My application working fine in a debug build in iPhone. But when I released my application in TestFlight it was not loading the screen, rather a blank white screen is there. I understand that there is an issue even my application running fine in debug mode. Below is my Log when I run my application in debug mode. What should I fix?

```
2022-02-25 11:17:12.774524+0530 Runner[6850:1924407] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2022-02-25 11:17:12.774669+0530 Runner[6850:1924407] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-02-25 11:17:12.934307+0530 Runner[6850:1924671] 7.3.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000005] No app has been configured yet.
2022-02-25 11:17:13.121695+0530 Runner[6850:1924706] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:49933/83eWeoTylZM=/
2022-02-25 11:17:13.436508+0530 Runner[6850:1924672] 7.3.0 - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS025027] Deferring to Google Analytics for Firebase for event data collection.
2022-02-25 11:17:14.240982+0530 Runner[6850:1924407] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process Runner
2022-02-25 11:17:14.241081+0530 Runner[6850:1924407] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
2022-02-25 11:17:14.241159+0530 Runner[6850:1924407] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
2022-02-25 11:17:14.768511+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: User granted permission
2022-02-25 11:17:15.562956+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: IN
2022-02-25 11:17:15.564043+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: FirebaseMessaging token: fVnOeuHXGUasmyCLLJzNrR:NWabxoeGMD2Mro2yMDP8ef81_PQs4Je5MDZBWbN5wIAPzzLcsUiRwWuD8hCFptzKW1F1IfudU5EKD4d325CCVWA_dnHUa9iSPbZy-Wo67LZG
2022-02-25 11:17:15.602857+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: *** Request ***
2022-02-25 11:17:15.610601+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: uri: 
2022-02-25 11:17:15.610711+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: method: GET
2022-02-25 11:17:15.610791+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: responseType: ResponseType.json
2022-02-25 11:17:15.610858+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: followRedirects: true
2022-02-25 11:17:15.610920+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: connectTimeout: 0
2022-02-25 11:17:15.611118+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: receiveTimeout: 20000
2022-02-25 11:17:15.611419+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: extra: {}
2022-02-25 11:17:15.611480+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter: headers:
2022-02-25 11:17:15.611559+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter:  content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
2022-02-25 11:17:15.611620+0530 Runner[6850:1924687] flutter:
2022-02-25 11:17:15.618508+0530 Runner[6850:1924671] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C1.1 142.250.183.10:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed
2022-02-25 11:17:15.618558+0530 Runner[6850:1924671] [connection] nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_write_handler [C1.1 142.250.183.10:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for write_timeout failed
```

Comment: Are you shrinking your app? Maybe some problem with this.

Comment: Same issue for me stuck from yesterday for this one

Comment: @3squad No I haven't Shrunk the app.

Comment: Sometimes libraries are using sample code related to *(Info).plist file where user put e.g. some token, or something else that is not configured with production version. I was having that kind of issue with Firebase. Maybe something with config related with production. Additionally try to add some alerts, and put them in some places in your app code and try verify where the real problem is.